# Splunk : How to query splunk dashboard using CURL command and save data in to Json file

Tags: splunk-query

Help is needed,

I am running below command on CLI and I am getting an error

Curl command:

```
curl -k -u xxxxx@url.com:xxxxx \
    https://splunk.com/en-US/app/search/search/jobs/export \
    -d search="searchindex=test" -d output_mode=json
```

output:

```
<html>
    <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
        <hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.2</center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about splunk API, but for whatever reason, you're getting HTTP 302 redirect, use `-L` with your `curl` command if you wish to follow it (perhaps it leads to a login page as authentication did not succeed?)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the network tools in Chrome to view the requests sent to the server... when you make the requests in Chrome you'll be able to see whats going on behind the scenes via `Developer Tools` -> `Network` tab) You'll be able to view the contents of any requests that are made, the `Request Headers` set, data sent, etc. and replicate it from there. You'll likely need a valid session cookie. Check the cookies tab for the request and you'll see those there... Also don't assume they'll be the same over time. They'll likely expire.